# Will ember rerender all li's in DOM in this case when i update arrayController contents

Tags: javascript, optimization, ember.js

```
{{#each App.usersController}}
    <li> 
        <span>{{name}}</span> ,
        <span>{{age}}</span>,
        <span>{{phone}}</span>,
        <span>{{address}}</span>
    </li>
{{/each}}
```

consider `usersController` is an `ArrayController` and has 100 users.

now I change that 100 users to another 150 users by doing,

```
App.usersController.set('content', newUsers);//newUsers.length = 150
```

Now will this result in removal of 100 `li` from `DOM` and then insertion of 150 `li` to `DOM` ? what is the optimal way to do this to maximize performance in a mobile browser (iphone)?

---

In my scenario I have 5 types of users shown in 5 different tabs, and i keep one controller each for each type and keeps the whole thing in DOM and just show/hide on changing tabs.

So i have 500 `li` in `DOM` which i show/hide. Now thinking some way to use a single `usersController` and somehow optimize the `DOM` updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case you have a lot of list items, I would suggest using [ember-list-view](https://github.com/emberjs/list-view), which reuses DOM elements instead of creating new ones and destroyng others.

Have a look [here](https://github.com/emberjs/list-view) for more info on that. Also [this introductory talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i3vEjbjV8Sk) by the creator Erik Bryn is very informative.

Hope it helps.